# Error when passing variables between two view controllers Swift

Tags: swift, variables

I've been struggling with this for awhile and I'm close to having a functional app so pulling my hair out. I've gotten some basic information from Facebook graph request and pulled the name out of the dictionary. I then am using prepareforsegue to pass the name to the second view controller. I plan on using the 'name' in a variety of different scenarios as a unique identifier.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error which I have no idea how to fix: 'Value of Type 'UIStoryboardSegue' has no member 'SecondViewController'. I have declared the var in the second view controller: var destViewController: String!

Any pointers would be so appreciated. I am very frustrated as I can't move on to anything else until this is working.

The code is here:

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions:     ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                print("Cancelled")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {

        }
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, relationship_status, gender, location, education"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            print(fbDetails)

            if let userDataDict = result as? NSDictionary {
             let name = userDataDict["name"] as? String

                func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: Any!) {
                    if (segue.identifier == "loginToHome") {
                        //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
                        // segues attached to same view
                        var destViewController = segue.SecondViewController as? SecondViewController;
                        destViewController.name = name

                        var bookUniverse = [String]()

                    }


            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put the prepare for segue function within the FBSDKGraphRequest. You should put this instead:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToHome", sender: self)
```

and rather than passing only the name, why not have a model object within the second ViewController that you can pass? If you are pretty set on having the name, make a class variable and assign the name to that, then pass the class variable to the second viewcontroller.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: Any!) {
                if (segue.identifier == "loginToHome") {
                    //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
                    // segues attached to same view
                    var destViewController = segue.SecondViewController as? SecondViewController;
                    destViewController.name = name

                    var bookUniverse = [String]()

                }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right now, I'm just trying to grab the name. If I use class, you mean like this:                                                                 class name {
    static let userName = "name"
}

Comment: Sorry, I have another question and I apologize. I'm learning still. Where am I putting the class. At the top with the first one? Thanks so much!

Comment: so what you want to do is beneath your class instantiation, you'd do : fileprivate var someVariableName:String = name. then you can just do: destViewController.name = someVariableName